# cx_freeze, mpl_toolkits/basemap/ how include the data folder in the build library.zip

Tags: python, python-2.7, cx-freeze, matplotlib-basemap

I am struggling a lot trying to create a .exe for my Gui originaly coded with opensuse. I am trying to make the .exe for windows (under XP). cx_freeze seems to work better for my case. The build folder is created properly but when I try to run .exe I have the following error :

> "proj data directory not found. Expecting it at C:\Python\build\exe.win32-2.7\library.zip\mpl_toolkits\basemap\data "

So do you know how I could do my setup.py in order to copy the folder mpl_toolkits\basemap\data to library.zip?

Comment: Could we see your setup.py file?

Comment: Why XP? I suggest going back to Windows 95 instead.

Comment: There's a `zip_includes` options ([docs](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html#build-exe)), but I don't know if the relevant code can actually load it from a zip file. You may need to use `include_files` and point it to the right place ([docs on using data files](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#using-data-files)).

Answer (score -2):

Here I posted my working solution for the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26519937/2741329

My fix requires 2 changes:
- Adding the files to include in the cx_freeze setup script
- Adding an OS environment variable in the user script

A similar issue with the same fix was also adressed [here](http://osdir.com/ml/python-cx-freeze-user/2010-07/msg00033.html) by simply adding in the setup file a list of tuple for `include_files` as `[("C:\\Python31\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyQt4\\mpl-data", "mpl-data")]`
This is not enough for Basemap since cx_freeze put by default its scripts into a zipped file.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @j0e3gan: added more details