# Can´t freeze a script with matplotlib basemap and cx_freeze

Tags: cx-freeze, matplotlib-basemap

back again. I am still working on it but I can not fix it

The script is running fine but when I freeze it using cx_freeze  a cx_freeze error appears.

at the end of the message says

OSError:proj data directory not found. Expecting it at: C:\python34........mpl_toolkits\basemap\data

Is the data not included in the build directory created by cx_freeze ?

I am using the following script for freezing

```
base = None

def find_data_file(pyproj):
    if getattr(sys,'XXXXs.exe',False):
        datadir = os.path.dirname(sys.aaEjecutable.py)
    else:
        datadir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    return os.path.join(datadir,pyproj)

if (sys.platform == "win32"):
    base = "Win32GUI"

exe = Executable(
        script = "Conver.py",  
        icon = "logo4.ico",
        targetName = "XXXXs.exe", 
        base = base
        )
includefiles = ["Logo1.jpg","Logo2R.jpg","Logo2R.jpg","logo4.ico",
                (('C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits'),("mpl_toolkits"))] 
setup(
    name = "Conver",
    version = "V3",
    description = "conve",
    author = "Jose ",
    options = {"build_exe": {"include_files":includefiles}}, 
    executables = [exe]
)
```

I think that something is wrong whit it. I must include the basemap but I dont't know how to do it

I can not go foward. The script is fine but I can use it in a computer with no python

Thanks

Comment: Even if it's included, it may not be usable: cx_Freeze puts packages into a zip file, and matplotlib might expect it to be a regular folder.

Comment: How can I fix the problem ?

Comment: Copy the basemap/data directory into your build directory with the includefiles option. Then set the environment variable `BASEMAPDATA` to the location of that directory before loading basemap in your code. [See the FAQ](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#data-files) for how to calculate that location.

Comment: Well I am going too slow, anyway I expect to fix it. I edited my freezing script including:                                    options = {"build_exe":     {"include_files":[( matplotlib.get_data_path(),"mpl-    data"),"Logo3.jpg","Logo2.jpg","Logo1.jpg","icon.ico"],}},                           I can see that a folder with the basemapdata is included into the build, but the problem still on. I understand that I must modify the scrip (not the script for freezing ) in order to know where the basemapdata are when it is freeze. I saw the link recomended but I can not understand how to do it thnaks

Comment: It will look *something like* `if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False): os.environ['BASEMAPDATA'] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable), 'basemapdata')`. You'll probably have to tweak that a bit, but it basically says: if running in a frozen application, set the BASEMAPDATA environment variable to a path calculated from my exe location.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue using Python 3.4 and cx_freeze 4.3.3. My fix required 2 changes:

1. In the cx_freeze setup script:

   ```
   buildOptions = dict( include_files = [("C:/Python34/Lib/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data","data")])
   ```
2. In my module where I am using Basemap:

   ```
   import sys, os
   if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
      os.environ['BASEMAPDATA'] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable), 'data')
   from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
   ```

As requested, my full setup script is:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

buildOptions = dict(packages = ['osgeo._gdal'], excludes = [], \
    include_files = [("C:/Python34/Lib/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data","data")])

import sys
base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform=='win32' else None

executables = [
  Executable('main.py', base=base, targetName = 'xxxxxxx.exe', icon='ico/xxxxx.ico')
  ]

setup(name='Xxxxx',
  version = '0.0.1',
  description = 'Xxxxx xxxx xxxx',
  author = 'xxxxxxx@xxx.edu',
  options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
  executables = executables)
```

Comment: Still does not run.       Error: OSError: proj data directory not found. Expecting at: C:\\Python34.........library.zip\mpl_toolkits\basemap\data   could you show me your setup script ?

Comment: I believe that the problem is not in the setup script. Do you have in the build directory the `Data` folder?

Comment: Point 1 of my answer makes cx_freeze copying the 'data' folder content in the 'build' directory, then point 2 says to Basemap where it can find the 'data'. Point 2 **must** come before the Basemap import wherever you use it! If you change the `os.environ['BASEMAPDATA']`, the error message should be at least change in the `Expecting at:` part. Hope this clarifies!

Comment: Well I think smoething is running... I included in the begining of my script (who runs with matplotlib base map) But now a different error appears when I run the exe file. ''Import error: No module named ' matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg'.    Thanks for your cooperation

Comment: Which type of backend are you using? Is `tk` actually required by your application?  I use both `pyside` and `pyqt` without problems. However, I believe that you should make a brand-new question on your new issue, and maybe accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

A way to always get the basemap data directory, with out hard coding

`import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits import basemap
build_options = dict( include_files = [(basemap.basemap_datadir, 'data')])`